# Unity not destroying object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ArrowScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        //GameObject effect = Instantiate(hiteffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        //Destroy(effect, 5f)
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this I have no idea could it be a problem with visual studios

https://ibb.co/FqLTVB7
https://ibb.co/5F5wKFL

[image: visualstudio]

Comment: What is the problem? Errors? Not compiling? What is `gameObject`? Need much more details to be able to answer this.

Comment: it just does nothing because it does not enter loop the Destroy(gameObject) should destroy the arrow clone and when i type a space in to visual studios it changes to the color that it should be

Comment: Odds are your method isn't being called and your problem lies outside this code snippet. Do the game objects involved in the collision have the appropriate components for collision detection?

Comment: Maybe https://ibb.co/FqLTVB7 https://ibb.co/5F5wKFL those are the 2 objects

Comment: You could try making the collider on the arrow a trigger, and instead of `OnCollisionEnter2D` you could use `OnTriggerEnter2D`. Also make sure you are using 2D colliders instead of 3D :). Maybe the thing hit by the arrow does not have a collider, or none of them have a `RigidBody2D` component. There are a lot of possibilities for the amount of information provided.

Comment: @DavidG `.gameObject` refers to the `GameObject` to which the script is attached. It's a Unity thing.

Comment: https://ibb.co/DY9HhTs i made it a trigger and when i shot it instantly does this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! your code is clearly `c#` ... Also just because you use a certain IDE (visual Studio) doesn't mean your question is about that IDE .. what you should do so is use `unity3d` since this is the main framework and API you are using ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnTriggerEnter2D worked but I had a bug where it said I was still using it it was because the arrow was inside my player that it was summoning from so the prefab was getting instantly destroyed. Thanks for all the help

Comment: ye forgot to do that :)